# Swift use of unresolved identifier 'webView'

Tags: swift, webview

I want to add a webview to my application, but i keep getting this freaking error for webview. Please help!

```
import UIKit

class Browse: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var browseweb: UIWebView!
    let browseurl = "http://google.com"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:browseurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is called `browseweb`, but you call `webView.loadRequest(request)`. You need to use the same name...

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry. Didn't see that. Still an amateur at this haha.

Comment: So what would I write then?

Comment: browserweb.loadRequest(request)